# Получение ответа от администратора телеграмм бота, аиограм

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, виртуальная-машина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть телеграмм бот. Человек покупает определенный товар, отправляет скриншот чека оплаты (оплата просто на карту) и этот чек перенаправляется администратору телеграмм канала. Под чеком расположена информация о клиенте и две инлайн кнопки: "Готово" и "Некорректное фото". Этапы проходят через машину состояний. Вопрос: Как записать ответ от администратора (какую из инлайн кнопок он нажал)? Телеграмм бот ждёт ответа от обычного пользователя, а инлайн кнопки и ответ поступает от администратора.